# How to call API inside switch case

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have created a tab component where I have three tabs each tab will contain data from different end points. I have planned to hit API's using switch case since I am having different end points. I have created a onChange function  where  I used to call three different end points, unfortunately I couldn't able to achieve the result, I am getting error stating that useEffect cannot be used inside onChange. Could anyone guide me to achieve the result. Thanks in advance.

API'S I am using are :https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1, https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2, https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";

const Tabb = () => {
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      });
  });

  const handleChange = (e, value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 0:
        break;

      case 1:
        break;

      case 2:
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
    setProfileData(value);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "40%" }}>
      <h2>Tbas in React JS</h2>

      <Paper square>
        <Tabs
          value={profileData}
          textColor="primary"
          indicatorColor="primary"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <Tab label="Tab One" />
          <Tab label="Tab Two" />
          <Tab label="Tab Three" />
        </Tabs>
        {/* <h3>Tab NO: {value} clicked!</h3> */}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need of `switch` block in this case

Answer (score 2):

You have a single API with a changing page parameter. Whenever you set the page (tab changed), update the state with the number of the page.

Set the `page` as the `useEffect()` dependency, so an API call would be issued whenever the page changes. Add the current page to the base query url to the current `url`.

Demo - choose a tab in the select menu:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Paper = 'div';
const Tabs = 'select';
const Tab = ({ label, ...rest }) => (<option {...rest}>{label}</option>);

const Demo = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`;
  
    fetch(url)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      });
  }, [page]);

  const handleChange = e => {  
    setPage(+e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Tabs onChange={handleChange}>
        <Tab label="Tab One" value={1} />
        <Tab label="Tab Two" value={2} />
        <Tab label="Tab Three" value={3} />
      </Tabs>
      {/* <h3>Tab NO: {value} clicked!</h3> */}
    </Paper>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question/issue you want to conditionally fetch some data and update state via a `switch` statement.

## Issues

1. The `useEffect` without a dependency will be called every render cycle. This is likely ***not*** what you want.
2. You can't conditionally call hooks in loops and callbacks, they must only be called from react functions and other custom hooks.

## Solution

I don't think you need the `useEffect` hook at all, you can define a function to handle the fetch, or better, just use a single fetch in the `onClick` handler.

```
const handleChange = (e, value) => {
  let url;
  switch (value) {
    case 0:
    default:
      url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
      break;

    case 1:
      url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
      break;

    case 2:
      url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3";
      break;
  }

  fetch(url)
    .then((results) => results.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
    });

  setProfileData(value);
};
```

You can simplify this a bit more, the switch cases are basically just adding `1` to the `value` and forming the url. Just use a string template to form the request URL.

```
const handleChange = (e, value) => {
  fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${value + 1}`)
    .then((results) => results.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
    });

  setProfileData(value);
};
```